# Pressure change due to Temperature change in a pipe

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, fluid-statics

I want to know how the following formula is derived:

$$\Delta P=\frac{B\Delta T}{0.884\frac Rt+A}$$

where $\Delta P$ is the pressure change, $B$ is the difference between water and steel thermal expansion coefficients, $R$ is the internal radius of the pipe,
$t$ is the thickness of the pipe and $A$ is the isothermal compressibility of water.

Comment: Where did you find the formula?

Comment: This formula is used for hydrotests of a pipeline.

Comment: But do you have a source? I'm unable to find that exact version of the equation.

Comment: Sorry but I do not have the source, which is why I want to know how it was derived. Were you able to find any related equation?

Comment: Hello! I have edited your question using MathJax (LaTeX) math typesetting. For future questions, you can refer to [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/). Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula you give is an approximate version of the general formula,

$$
\Delta P = \frac{\Delta T(\alpha_v-3\alpha_l)}{A+\left(\frac{R}{Et}\right)(2.5-2\mu)},
$$

where $\alpha_v$ is the cubic expansion coefficient of the liquid, $\alpha_l$ is the linear expansion coefficient of the wall, $E$ is the modulus of elasticity for the wall, $\mu$ is Poisson's ratio and the other variables are as you give them. I have assumed there is no leakage across the valve, if there is leakage then there is an additional term in the numerator.

Your formula comes from taking particular values for $\mu$ and $E$. You can find the general formula and more detail in the pdf linked to in the comments of [this Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/ChemicalEngineering/comments/ageuw8/calculate_pressure_change_due_to_temperature/).

Comment: The link isn't working for me.

Comment: Changed the link to the reddit post where I found the doc which I tried to link to.